# NSMutableDictionary don't set value for key

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a code in which the existing handle dates in an array, separates the day of the month and will put inside a NSMutableDictionary with their respective day of the month, the array has the following structure:

```
"12/01/2014" //Structure of my date is -> dd-mm-yyyy
"16/01/2014"
"30/01/2014"
"02/02/2014"
"08/02/2014"
```

I use this code to put this values inside a NSMutableDictionary:

```
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(int x=0;x<[list count];x++){

        NSMutableArray *lstaInfo2 = [[list[x] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];

        if([lstaInfo2[1]  isEqual: @"01"]){

            [dictionary setValue:list[x] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"January of %@",lstaInfo2[2]]];

        }
        if([lstaInfo2[1]  isEqual: @"02"]){

            [dictionary setValue:list[x] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"February of %@",lstaInfo2[2]]];
        }

}
```

The values ​​that I hoped to return within the variable dictionary is:

```
January of 2014 =>

"12/01/2014"
"16/01/2014"
"30/01/2014"

February of 2014 =>

"02/02/2014"
"08/02/2014"
```

But the variable dictionary, returns only the last values, like this:

```
January of 2014 =>

    "30/01/2014"

February of 2014 =>

    "08/02/2014"
```

why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A dictionary will only hold one entry per unique key value.  If you want more you need to insert an array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(int x=0;x<[list count];x++){

    NSString* key = [self getKeyForDate:list[x]];
    NSMutableArray* listForMonth = dictionary[key];
    if (key == nil) {
        listForMonth = [NSMutableArray array];
        [dictionary setValue:listForMonth forKey:key];
    }
    [listForMonth addObject:list[x]];
}

.....
```

In `init`

```
monthArray = @[@"January", @"February", @"March" ...
```

Separate method:

```
-(NSString*) getKeyForDate:(NSString*)date {
    NSMutableArray *lstaInfo2 = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
    NSInteger monthNum = lstaInfo2[0].integerValue;
    NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat;@"%@ of %@", monthArray[monthNum-1], lstaInfo2[2]]; 
    return result;
}
```

You can also use NSDateFormatter to parse the date, and NSCalendar to serve up the month names, but that's getting too deep for one lesson.

Comment: Thanks for you too, simply code and works as well thanks +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

When you try to add new value to the dictionary check whether value for this key is actually in the dictionary. If no, create and set `NSMutableArray` object for this key and add values to this array.

Try this:

```objc

```
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(int x=0; x < [list count]; x++){

    NSArray *lstaInfo2 = [list[x] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *key;

    if([lstaInfo2[1]  isEqual: @"01"]){
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"January of %@",lstaInfo2[2]];

    }
    if([lstaInfo2[1]  isEqual: @"02"]){
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"February of   %@",lstaInfo2[2]];
    }
    if (key) { 
        //if there is no value for the specified key create and set 
        //NSMutableArray object for this key, otherwise keep value for
        //the key without modyfing it.
        dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] ?: [NSMutableArray array]; 
        [dictionary[key] addObject:list[x]];
    }
```

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `setValue:forKey:` doesn't append to the current value. So in the first iteration through the loop you set `"January of 2014" => ["12", "01", "2014"]` and in the next iteration you set `"January of 2014" => ["16", "01", "2014"]`, and so on. You want to map from a string to a NSMutableArray.

I would really suggest you use the NSDateFormatter class for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdateformatter_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/. It will be easier and much more flexible than manually parsing the dates.